# What is the convention for tickers on the Singapore Exchange?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, singapore

On the Singapore Exchange (SGX), I observed that 3 letter tickers are for ordinary equities, whereas 4 letter tickers depends on the last letter. From my observations, these are the meanings of the last letter of 4 letter tickers:

- W = warrant
- U = unit trust
- D = depository receipts
- S = Singapore government bonds
- Z = bonds?
- B = bonds?

What are Z and B? For example, "Temasek 2.7% 231025XB#" is "TEKB", while "CapMallTrb3.08%210220" is "TY6Z". What's the difference?

What about preferred shares? I noticed that preferred shares have 3 letter tickers. For example: "CITYDEV NCCPS" is "C70".

What are the conventions for tickers on the Singapore Exchange? Is there an official document that explains SGX's policy on stock tickers?

Comment: Probably easiest to ask them.  Tickers are usually negotiated when discussing listing on a particular exchange by the firm doing the listing.  They may have conventions for suffixes for different security types to distinguish them.  Too much similarity with existing tickers on other exchanges can cause problems with people buying the wrong stock and wanting the transaction to be reversed later.  Better to use ISINs or more specific identifiers if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Google to see if you can find a list of symbol suffixes.  Here's an example of what I'm suggesting.  It's for US [symbols](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/nasdaqfifthcharactersuffixlist.pdf).

If you can't find such a list, while it's a bit more work, you could download the entire list of symbols from the SGX exchange and distill it down to a list of all of the symbol suffixes.  For those that you are not familiar with, look up the symbol in Yahoo Finance or whatever site offers Singapore information and then read the profile of that security.

Again for the US, preferred letter suffixes are arbitrary.  They have no inherent meaning other than differentiation from other issues.  A company might start with 'A' and each subsequent issue will follow alphabetically.  Sometimes issues are called in non alphabetical order and gaps arise in the sequence (A, B, D, F).  So rather than add the next new issue sequentially when there's a new issue, they fill in the sequence.

For specific details about preferred stocks, see if you can find a web site dedicated to them.  The best one available in the US is QUANTUMONLINE and for us, it offers a link to the EDGAR prospectus which offers detailed issue information.